# How to convert a PDF to Bitmap (rasterized) in C++ (without .NET)

Tags: c++, pdf, bitmap, rasterize

How can I convert a PDF to a bitmap (as in an array of pixels, not the .bmp file format) using C++ in a way that will work on both Mac and Windows? On Mac I may be able to use CoreGraphics to do it, but that doesn't give me a windows solution. I have found numerous libraries that claim to do this that require .NET, but that is not an option either.

I need to:

- Support multiple page PDFs and get a bitmap for each image that I can process
- Do this on both Windows and Mac. I have a solution on Mac, so worst case a Windows-only solution would be acceptable.
- Not be tied to a GPL license
- Keep the size as small as possible; this is being used from a browser plugin, so calling external applications or having large dependencies would be significant disadvantages.

Any ideas?

Comment: [Stack Overflow doesn't provide product or service recommendations](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128562/166663).

Comment: A library is a product, and you're asking for someone to recommend one.

Comment: I am asking for a solution to a programming problem. I rather expect that any suggestions will come as "use ... library", but perhaps I worded the question badly.

Comment: You've put enough restrictions in the question that commercial products may be the only thing left.

Comment: not my choice; .Net is simply not an option for our application. I'd prefer it were cross platform, but windows-only would be a possibility if I can't get that since there is a Mac option. GPL is also not an option because we aren't releasing our application as GPL.

Comment: ImageMagick comes immediately to mind, and the [license seems OK](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/license.php). You have to attribute in your documentation, but you don't have to open-source your own code.

Comment: @ildjarn - I think you're taking that directive too literally. There is always room for manoeuvre in the guidelines, and an answer that recommends a library should be fine. The question seems well-considered and pre-researched to me, which is primarily what we should be concerned with.

Comment: You're probably going to be best off buying a solution.  Libraries to accomplish this are usually only a few hundred per developer.  Alternatively, the specs for PDFs aren't that crazy to implement yourself.

Comment: For future readers of this post, [Amyuni PDF Creator ActiveX](http://www.amyuni.com/en/developer/pdfcreatoractivex/) fulfill these requirements. The method [DrawCurrentPage](http://www.amyuni.com/WebHelp/Amyuni_PDF_Creator_for_ACTIVE_X/Using_the_PDF_Creator_Control/Methods/Page_Handling/DrawCurrentPage_Method.htm) allows drawing a page of a PDF file into a device context, which can be created from a bitmap using GDI. *usual disclaimer applies*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about on Windows, but on Mac OS X the system has built-in support for rendering PDFs. You can simply create an [`NSImage`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaDrawingGuide/Images/Images.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003290-CH208-SW16) that is backed by an [`NSPDFImageRep`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSPDFImageRep_Class/Reference/Reference.html).